# Is there a newer/better book than Genome-Scale Algorithm Design available? It's from 2015

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequencing, sequence-analysis

I'm considering buying the book "Genome-Scale Algorithm Design: Biological Sequence Analysis in the Era of High-Throughput Sequencing" by Veli Mäkinnen and others.

However, as this book was published 6 years ago (2015) I wonder if there's a newer and better book on the topic of genome-scale algorithms?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A suggestion if you get no satisfaction here is our sister site [bioinformatics.se].

Comment: Please read the description of the purpose of this site o the [Tour]. It is a question and answer site about problems in biology. Subjective opinions of a book are not that.

Comment: The book I ask about is on topic to this site. If you cannot offer to help or answer my question, please refrain from commenting/posting.